# Add centered text to the middle of a horizontal rule

Tags: html, css, xhtml, line, vertical-alignment

I'm wondering what options one has in xhtml 1.0 strict to create a line on both sides of text like-so:

```
Section one
----------------------- Next section -----------------------
Section two
```

I've thought of doing some fancy things like this:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 44%;"><hr/></div>
<div style="float:right; width: 44%;"><hr/></div>
Next section
```

Or alternatively, because the above has problems with alignment (both vertical and horizontal):

```
<table><tr>
<td style="width:47%"><hr/></td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center">Next section</td>
<td style="width:47%"><hr/></td>
</tr></table>
```

This also has alignment problems, which I solve with this mess:

```
<table><tr>
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray; width: 47%">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center" rowspan="2">Next section</td>
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray; width: 47%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
```

In addition to the alignment problems, both options feel 'fudgy', and I'd be much obliged if you happened to have seen this before and know of an elegant solution.

Comment: Here's another thread with a no-extra-tags challenge - and a solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648513/css-challenge-can-i-do-this-without-introducing-more-html#comment17061217_12648513

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle is still the best solution.

Comment: A useful answer here would employ CSS Grid.

Comment: Added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54034010/1891677) (SCSS) which transforms almost any element into a divider without set background and allows setting: color and stroke style (solid, dotted, dashed) of the divider, position of text (left, right, center), as well as the class which applies this (by default `.divider`).

Comment: Given [current flexbox support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) I think [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634224/465233) could gain some visibility.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Flexbox is the solution:

```css
.separator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.separator::before,
.separator::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.separator:not(:empty)::before {
  margin-right: .25em;
}

.separator:not(:empty)::after {
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">Next section</div>
```

Nowadays [every browser supports it](https://caniuse.com/flexbox), and you can ensure compatibility with decade-old browsers by adding respective vendor prefixes if needed. It would degrade gracefully anyways.

Comment: Best answer considering flexbox support these days

Comment: this is a nice solution

Comment: I believe placing a span and giving margins to it instead of pseudo classes is more flexible solution for providing margins to text. In this way, it can be used as a single separator component with or without a text.
`<div class="separator"><span>Next section</span></div>`
`.separator span { margin-left: .25em; margin-right: .25em; }`

Comment: @ErdemErgin I edited my answer to address your use-case.

Comment: perfect solution!

Comment: 10 years later, still the best solution found so far.

Answer (score 247):

How about:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
  <span style="font-size: 40px; background-color: #F3F5F6; padding: 0 10px;">
    Section Title <!--Padding is optional-->
  </span>
</div>
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crs8yenu/).

*You can use `vw` or `%` to make it responsive*.

Comment: Getting exact top value is a bit hard. It is not exactly -0.5em;

Comment: perfect. "Responsive" too

Comment: See my answer for a solution that doesn't require you to specify the background color or the width.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54034010/1891677) for responsive, transparent bg, variable style and height of divider, variable position of text. Can also be applied more than once to different selectors, for having more than one style of divider in the same project, using SCSS. Works with any `font-size`.

Answer (score 205):

The way to solve this without knowing the width and the background color is the following:

Structure

```
<div class="strike">
   <span>Kringle</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.strike {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.strike > span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: red;
}

.strike > span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.strike > span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Hnz/

**Double line**

To create a double line, use one of the following options:

1) Fixed space between lines

```
.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    border-top: 4px double red;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Hnz/103/

2) Custom space between lines

```
.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 5px; /* space between lines */
    margin-top: -2px; /* adjust vertical align */
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Hnz/105/

---

**SASS (SCSS) version**

Based on this solution, I added SCSS "with color property" if it could help someone...

```
//mixins.scss
@mixin bg-strike($color) {

    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 

    > span {

        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;

        &:before,
        &:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: 9999px;
            height: 1px;
            background: $color;
        }

        &:before {
            right: 100%;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }

        &:after {
            left: 100%;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```

example of use :

```
//content.scss
h2 {
    @include bg-strike($col1);
    color: $col1;
}
```

Comment: This version works better if you are using an image for the line -- or at least it is easier to edit and remain responsive

Comment: Very nice work! Can you use your wizardry to create a double line? (Otherwise, I'll just resort to using a tiny repeating background image.)

Comment: This is the best answer because it will work without the setting the background , and when you have to set the transparent background

Comment: Very nice example. Also you can align text to left, center and right and it works as expected - unwanted line will disappear. But you need to remove `text-align: center;` for this to work

Comment: To hide overflowing lines to both sides, just set `overflow: hidden` to the parent and voila, constrained striked lines.

Comment: An updated version that will show a single line without interruption when there is no title: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Hnz/1901/

Answer (score 108):

You can accomplish this with :before and :after without knowing the width of container or background color, and using them allows for greater styling of the line breaks. For example, this can be modified to make double-lines, dotted lines, etc.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8jddc0o/1/)

CSS, and HTML usage:

```css
.hr-sect {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    margin: 8px 0px;
}
.hr-sect:before,
.hr-sect:after {
    content: "";
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    height: 1px;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr-sect">CATEGORY</div>
```

SCSS Version:

```
.hr-sect {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    margin: 8px 0;

    &:before, &:after {
        content: "";
        flex-grow: 1;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        height: 1px;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 0 8px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution, though it has one caveat: if there will be no text, you'll still have a gap between lines.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution in this thread to be honest, the issue with no text can be overlooked since you would want the divider with text always.

Comment: Change `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);` with `border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);` to control the line style.

Answer (score 56):

Try this:

```css
.divider {
 width:500px;
 text-align:center;
}

.divider hr {
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:40%;

}

.left {
 float:left;
}

.right {
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
    <hr class="left"/>TEXT<hr class="right" />
</div>
```

Live preview on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpyszenj/).

Comment: It works perfectly and uses <hr /> so what possibly could be wrong with this answer? I say nothing.

Comment: +1 No need to mess with background color or use tags in unintended ways. One downside is that `.divider hr` width depends on how long the text is. Suggestion: `.divider` and `.divider hr` widths should be specified in `em` units. To get `hr` width, use (`.divider` width minus # of chars) / 2 .

Comment: 40% is wrong here. If the text is longer, it would mis-aligned

Answer (score 25):

I just came across the same problem, here is one way to solve it:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><hr /></td>
    <td style="width:1px; padding: 0 10px; white-space: nowrap;">Some text</td>
    <td><hr /></td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

It works without setting a background on the text element, i.e. it will look good regardless what background is behind it.

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/88vgS/

Comment: Doesn't solve the OP's problem. That creates two lines with text between them. He wants a line that's broken part way through and has text at the broken section, then the line continues.

Comment: It actually does what the OP is asking for. You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/88vgS/

Comment: Also, what is a line broken part way through, with text at the broken section, if not two lines with text in between them?

Comment: You should throw appropriate TR tags in there. I think that's what got me confused for a moment. I originally thought for some reason it was on three lines, not three columns. Correct markup probably wouldn't have caused me to see it that way. Regardless, it's definitely a workable solution.

Comment: But this uses tables, that is a NOT ALLOWED! Oh, just kidding. GRIDS have their place, almost all other GUI XML frameworks recognize that and use them everywhere (e.g. WPF / XAML). Thanks for the solution mate! This deserves more than 3 up votes. I suspect people's aversion to the hated tables will be an obstacle though.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE:** This will not work using HTML5

Instead, check out this question for more techniques: [CSS challenge, can I do this without introducing more HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648513/css-challenge-can-i-do-this-without-introducing-more-html)

---

I used `line-height:0` to create the effect in the header of my site [guerilla-alumnus.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20140517093934/http://guerilla-alumnus.com/)

```
<div class="description">
   <span>Text</span>
</div>

.description {
   border-top:1px dotted #AAAAAA;
}

.description span {
   background:white none repeat scroll 0 0;
   line-height:0;
   padding:0.1em 1.5em;
   position:relative;
}
```

---

Another good method is on http://robots.thoughtbot.com/

He uses a background image and floats to achieve a cool effect

Comment: I like this, it looks great on your site, but I couldn't get it to work (I suspect interference from jQuery css). :( But it is really cool.

Comment: I think your h1 is pushing the span down.

Comment: This is a "hack" that employs the different rendering behaviour for DOCTYPE XTHML 1.0 Transitional. If you use DOCTYPE html (for HTML5), it will NOT work.

Answer (score 7):

```
<div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid black">
  <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: -10px; background-color: white; padding: 0px 10px">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap grid:

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="row vertical-center">
    <div class="col-xs-5"><hr></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="color: white"> Text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"><hr></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.vertical-center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: The `vertical-center` class no longer exists in bootstrap (4.3.1). Could you please update your answer to say `align-items-center`?

Answer (score 6):

If you can use CSS and are willing to use the deprecated `align` attribute, a styled fieldset/legend will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
fieldset { 
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
</style>

<fieldset>
<legend align="center">First Section</legend>
Section 1 Stuff
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend align="center">Second Section</legend>
Section 2 Stuff
</fieldset>
```

The intended purpose of a fieldset is to logically group form fields.  As willoler pointed out, a `text-align: center` style for will not work for `legend` elements.  `align="center"` is deprecated HTML but it should center the text properly in all browsers.

Comment: A more detailed explanation of what I was going for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<legend>` takes on the display traits of a `block` or `inline-block` element, as it can be padded *and* margined, which means `text-align:center` shouldn't work...

Comment: yeah legends are great for semantics - i use them for wrapping radio groups but they are notoriously stubborn

Comment: I corrected my answer.  Unfortunately due to the stubbornness of certain browsers in styling the `legend` element, `align="center"` is the only solution I could find that reliably centers a `legend`.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use position relative and set a height on the parent

```css
.fake-legend {
  height: 15px;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.fake-legend span {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="fake-legend"><span>Or</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Heres a simple solution with css only, no background tricks...

```
.center-separator {
    display: flex;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: gray;
}

.center-separator::before, .center-separator::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    background: gray;
    height: 1px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="center-separator">
    centered text
  </div>
```

example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lkj6wd3/

Comment: Great and reusable solution, like a utility class.

Answer (score 6):

With Bootstrap 4 this seems to be working for me:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><hr/></div>
  <div class="col-auto">Or</div>
  <div class="col"><hr/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<fieldset style="border:0px; border-top:1px solid black">
    <legend>Test</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Evil hack ...

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hack, but I would test that it works in all browsers you intend to support.

Comment: fieldset doesn't want to be used like that, it's been hacked into place ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Bumping up a 2 year old post, but here is how I approach these situations using only one element and CSS.

```
​h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('http://heritageonfifth.com/images/seperator.png') left center repeat-x;
    width: 15%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

h1:after{
    background-position: right center;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

​And here is a fiddle to check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/sRhBc/ (random image from Google taken for the border).

The only drawback of this approach is that it doesn't support IE7.

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing a `fieldset`, and aligning the "legend" element (your "next section" text) to the middle of the field with only `border-top` set. I'm not sure about how a legend is positioned in accordance with the fieldset element. I imagine it might just be a simple `margin: 0px auto` to do the trick, though.

example :

```
<fieldset>
      <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Woohoo my first post even though this is a year old. To avoid the background-coloring issues with wrappers, you could use inline-block with hr (nobody said that explicitly). Text-align should center correctly since they are inline elements.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <hr style="display:inline-block; position:relative; top:4px; width:45%" />
       &nbsp;New Section&nbsp;
    <hr style="display:inline-block; position:relative; top:4px; width:45%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a `h1` with a span in the middle.

HTML Example:

```
<h1><span>Test archief</span></h1>
```

CSS Example:

```
.archive h1 {border-top:3px dotted #AAAAAA;}
.archive h1 span { display:block; background:#fff; width:200px; margin:-23px auto; text-align:center }
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Youri. Instead of a `span`, you could consider using a `div`. It serves the same purpose, except it is naturally a block element. :)

Comment: @Nix Block element inside inline element? No thanks, span is a good choice

Comment: @MrAzulay `h1` is an inline element. `span` is nice for wrapping stuff, but the reason I prefer a `div` in this case, is because Youri use CSS to set the `span` to `display:block;`. I don't see the point of making an inline element into a block element, when there are suitable block elements (`div`) readily available.

Comment: @Nix Isn't that a pretty common thing to do? While putting blocks inside inline is bad practice imo. This is a good post about it http://skypoetsworld.blogspot.se/2008/10/dont-ever-put-block-inside-inline.html

Comment: Ooops, I mistyped in my latest comment. I agree that you shouldn't place a block inside an inline element, but `h1` is actually a BLOCK element. Sorry for the confusion. Still, I don't see the point of making a `span` into a block element, but fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at above, I modified to:

**CSS**

```
.divider {
    font: 33px sans-serif;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.divider span {
    position:relative;
}
.divider span:before, .divider span:after {
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 10em;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
}
.divider span:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left:10em;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divider">
    <span>This is your title</span></div>
```

Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Taking @kajic's solution and putting the styling in CSS:

```
<table class="tablehr">
  <td><hr /></td>
  <td>Text!</td>
  <td><hr /></td>
</table>
```

Then CSS (but it depends on CSS3 in using nth selector):

```
.tablehr { width:100%; }
.tablehr > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) { width:1px; padding: 0 10px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Cheers.

(P.S. On tbody and tr, Chrome, IE and Firefox at least automatically inserts a tbody and tr, which is why my sample, like @kajic's, didn't include these so as to keep things shorter in the needed html markup. This solution was tested with newest versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox, as of 2013).

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO PAGE**](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/wcDbB)

### HTML

```
<header>
  <h1 contenteditable>Write something</h1>
</header>
```

### CSS

```
header{ 
  display:table;
  text-align:center; 
}
header:before, header:after{ 
  content:'';
  display:table-cell; 
  background:#000; 
  width:50%;
  -webkit-transform:scaleY(0.3);
  transform:scaleY(0.3);
}
header > h1{ white-space:pre; padding:0 15px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and does not require background color behind the text to hide a border line, instead uses actual hr tag.  You can play around with the widths to get different sizes of hr lines.

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:45%"><hr width='80%' /></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width: 9%;text-align: center;vertical-align:90%;text-height: 24px"><h4>OR</h4></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:45%;float:right" ><hr width='80%'/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Use

```
    hr
    {
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
        color: #333;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    hr:after
    {
        content: "Or";
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: -0.7em;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0 0.25em;
        background: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpyszenj/439/) that uses FlexBox and will also give you different styles of HR (double line, symbols in the center of the line, drop shadow, inset, dashed, etc).

CSS

```
button {
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 2px;
  }

  button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  button.active {
    background-color: rgb(34, 179, 247);
    color: #fff;
  }

  .codeBlock {
    display: none;
  }

  .htmlCode, .cssCode {
    background-color: rgba(34, 179, 247, 0.5); 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .divider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .divider.fixed {
    width: 400px;
  }

  .divider > label {
    align-self: baseline;
    flex-grow: 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .divider > hr {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #666;
  }

  .divider.left > label {
    order: 1;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  .divider.left > hr {
    order: 2
  }

  .divider.right > label {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  /* hr bars with centered text */
  /* first HR in a centered version */

  .divider.center >:first-child {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  /* second HR in a centered version */

  .divider.center >:last-child {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  /** HR style variations **/

  hr.gradient {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #333, #f00);
  }

  hr.gradient2 {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  }

  hr.dashed {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px dashed #666;
  }

  hr.dropshadow {
    background: transparent;
    height: 12px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  hr.blur {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    /* Firefox... */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px black;
  }

  hr.blur:after {
    background: transparent;
    /* Not really supposed to work, but does */
    content: "\00a0";
    /* Prevent margin collapse */
  }

  hr.inset {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }

  hr.flared {
    background: transparent;
    overflow: visible;
    /* For IE */
    height: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  hr.flared:before {
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -31px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  hr.double {
    background: transparent;
    overflow: visible;
    /* For IE */
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: medium double #333;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
  }

  hr.double:after {
    background: transparent;
    content: "§";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.7em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="divider left">
  <hr />
  <label>Welcome!</label>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="divider right">
  <hr />
  <label>Welcome!</label>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="divider center">
  <hr />
  <label>Welcome!</label>
  <hr />
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="divider left fixed">
  <hr />
  <label>Welcome!</label>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="divider right fixed">
  <hr />
  <label>Welcome!</label>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="divider center fixed">
  <hr />
  <label>Welcome!</label>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Or here's an interactive Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpyszenj/439/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS flex property

HTML

```
<div class="hrtext">
  <div class="hrbefore">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="hrcontent">
    <h2>TABLE OF CONTENT</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hrafter">
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hrtext{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.hrbefore,.hrafter{
    flex:auto;
}
.hrcontent{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always the good old FIELDSET

```
 fieldset
 {
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-bottom: none;
 }
 fieldset legend
 {
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Fieldsets should only be used with forms.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.orSpan{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1.3rem;
  margin-left:50%;
  padding:0 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <hr> <span class="orSpan">OR</span>
</div>
```

> You may required to adjust the **margin** property

Answer (score 1):

## html

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;" class="add-heading">
    <hr class="add-hr">
    <h2>Add Employer</h2>
    <hr class="add-hr">
</div>
```

## css

```
.add-hr { 
    display: block; height: 1px;
    border: 0; border-top: 4px solid #000;
    margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; 
  }

.add-heading h2{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this with bootstrap:

```
<div class="text-center d-flex">
  <hr className="flex-grow-1" />
  <span className="px-2 font-weight-lighter small align-self-center">
    Hello
  </span>
  <hr className="flex-grow-1" />
</div>
```

[here is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VRpx.png)

Answer (score 1):

**[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#Specifying_what_elements_to_lay_out_as_flexible_boxes) and [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="divider">divider</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.divider {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c2c2c2;

    &::before,
    &::after {
        content: "";
        flex: 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    }
    &::before {
        margin-right: 0.25em;
    }
    &::after {
        margin-left: 0.25em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without `<hr />`. Semantically, design should be done with the means of CSS, in this case it is quite possible.

```
div.header
{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

div.line
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px dashed;
  z-index: -1;
}

<div class="header">
  Next section
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSS

```
.Divider {
width: 100%; height: 30px;  text-align: center;display: flex;
}
.Side{
width: 46.665%;padding: 30px 0;
}
.Middle{
width: 6.67%;padding: 20px 0;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="Divider">
    <div class="Side"><hr></div>
    <div class="Middle"><span>OR</span></div>
    <div class="Side"><hr></div>
</div>
```

You may modify the width in class "side" and "middle" based on the length of your text in the tag "span". Be sure the width of the "middle" plus 2 times of the width of "side" equal to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive, transparent background, variable height and style of divider, variable position of text, adjustable distance between divider and text.  Can also be applied multiple times with different selectors for multiple divider styles in same project.
SCSS below.

**Markup** (HTML):

```
<div class="divider" text-position="right">Divider</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.divider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.divider:before,
.divider:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  border-bottom: 5px dotted #ccc;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.divider:before {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.divider:after {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.divider[text-position="right"]:after,
.divider[text-position="left"]:before {
  content: none;
}
```

Without `text-position` it defaults to center.

Demo:

```css
.divider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.divider:before,
.divider:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  border-bottom: 5px dotted #ccc;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.divider:before {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.divider:after {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.divider[text-position="right"]:after,
.divider[text-position="left"]:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="divider" text-position="left">Divider</span>
<h2 class="divider">Divider</h2>
<div class="divider" text-position="right">Divider</div>
```

And **SCSS**, to modify it quickly:

```
$divider-selector    : ".divider";
$divider-border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.21);
$divider-padding     : 1rem;
$divider-border-width: 1px;
$divider-border-style: solid;
$divider-max-width   : 100%;

#{$divider-selector} {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 $divider-padding;
    max-width: $divider-max-width;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: '';
        flex: 0 1 100%;
        border-bottom: $divider-border-width $divider-border-style $divider-border-color;
        margin: 0 $divider-padding;
        transform: translateY(#{$divider-border-width} / 2)
    }

    &:before {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    &:after {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    &[text-position="right"]:after,
    &[text-position="left"]:before {
        content: none;
    }
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/gema34Lj/).

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your code snippet. If I put a text with divider other than english (in my case, korean), texts break line in every two letters. Could you figure out why?