# CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a horizontal rule with some text in the middle.
For example:

----------------------------------- my title here -----------------------------

Is there a way to do that in CSS? Without all the "-" dashes obviously.

Comment: For a solution over a **transparent background**, see [Line before and after centered text over transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-centered-text-over-transparent-background)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634224/465233

Comment: @G-Cyrillus This is a clearly established canonical with way more visibility/SEO and better answers (including a flexbox solution) than the one you linked to. It almost seems like a major reason for the action was to highlight your own answer, which would be an abuse of the dupehammer privilege IMHO.

Comment: @tyler, but obsolete for edges. whatever you like or dislike ;)  I reacted after an upvote and got surprised of that duplicte. bit you can select any others.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I meant you have your own solution here in addition to the other flex solutions :-)

Comment: @TylerH no trouble , to me playing around with tricks while flex is now well implemented everywhere is not usefull anymore for newbies falling here ;) there confused enough. there got to be better duplicates i believe.

Answer (score 619, accepted):

This is roughly how I'd do it: the line is created by setting a `border-bottom` on the containing `h2` then giving the `h2` a smaller `line-height`. The text is then put in a nested `span` with a non-transparent background.

```css
h2 {
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
   line-height: 0.1em;
   margin: 10px 0 20px; 
} 

h2 span { 
    background:#fff; 
    padding:0 10px; 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
<p>this is some content other</p>
```

I tested in Chrome only, but there's no reason it shouldn't work in other browsers.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/

Comment: This is my favourite solution.  It works on OSX too and some of the others dont.  If you use this solution remember to set the background of the span to the same color as the background of your page, it will be especially obvious what i mean if your background isn't white. ;)

Comment: This is not flexible, since you fix the background color of the text as white.

Comment: While this is easy and clever, this just creates a strike-through on the word and hides it with a padding and a background colour to the span. So if you have a background colour that is defined by the user, you have to change the background colour of the span as well. In my case, I enable user to switch between dark and lite mode. I have to update the span colour every-time the user switches the colour. That's a painful situation. So it's good idea to make use of the pseudo elements here, as written by @Puigcerber. So I made line is grey, will work in both lite and dark mode.

Comment: I create a small background .png image and put it as a background .

Comment: It's only worked for specific background color. It's not working when using transparent background

Answer (score 396):

After trying different solutions, I have come with one valid for different text widths, any possible background and without adding extra markup.

```css
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  background-color: #000;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}

h1::before {
  right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

h1::after {
  left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h1>This is a longer heading</h1>
```

I tested it in IE8, IE9, Firefox and Chrome. You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/vLwDf/1/

Comment: This really is a good solution; particularly as it works with any background and does not require a set width on the heading element.

Comment: This is great. I adapted your code a bit to left-align the text and make the `:after` element the width of the block.
I'm curious: what exactly is the role of `margin-right: -50%`? When I was fumbling around with code, missing that property would make the decoration break to another line. And even when `:after` is assigned 100% width, I still need the negative margin-right of 50% to make it fit. Why?

Comment: As I understand it, adding negative margins in both sides pulls the element in both direction so that's why it gets centered.

Comment: One of the things I love about this solution is that it works for situations where you don't know what color the background is. Easily the best solution so far for this problem.

Comment: I created a scss example with placeholder https://codepen.io/cmichael110/pen/KJLxBq. @Matt__C Your solution with the left  alignment is also a good thing - maybe someone here can extend it with a fullwidth line.

Comment: If you have small width and large text then the cross line is not working as expected.. wrap all the html in a div with width: 150px. How can you solve that? I'm looking a responsive solution as this part of my app will be shown in mobile devices

Comment: How can I restrict this to a certain class, as I can't have this applied to all of the heading, just to some of them. I trie to use "h2.titulo:before{..." but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that should work @emerson, or even just the class `.titulo:before`.

Comment: I think this is the more robust solution.  This will work if you need to insert an icon between the lines.

Comment: This will not work with media queries.

Comment: `::before` not `:before`

Comment: It's good solution but if you use language like Russian you need to add ```padding``` because this language have a letters like Й and top of this letter is hidden

Answer (score 195):

Here is Flex based solution.

[image: A heading with a central horizontal line to its sides]

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
h1:before, h1:after{
  content: "";
  flex: 1 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: auto;
}
h1:before {
  margin-right: 10px
}
h1:after {
  margin-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<h1>Today</h1>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0y7uaqL/

Comment: I use another element: `<h1><span>Today</span></h1>` with a margin/padding on the span.

Comment: The padding is achieved via the existing margin left/right you see in the demo.

Comment: If it's flex-based solution, I would add `align-items: center;` to the `h1` definition so no `margin: auto` is needed

Comment: This answer works for me the best, especially when it comes to themed applications

Answer (score 60):

Shortest and best method:

```css
span:after,
span:before{
    content:"\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<span> your text </span>
```

Comment: In my case line appeared to be a bit to thick, so I hacked it by assigning a different font family: `font-family: monospace;` worked fine.

Comment: this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 54):

Ok, this one is more complicated but it works in everything but IE<8

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  content: " ";
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1.2em;
}

span:after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><span>text TEXT</span></div>
```

The :before and :after elements are positioned absolutely so we can pull one to the left and one to the right. Also, the width (40% in this case) is very dependent of the width of the text inside.. have to think about a solution for that. At least the `top: 1.2em` makes sure the lines stay more or less in the center of the text even if you have different font size.

It does seem to work well though: http://jsfiddle.net/tUGrf/3/

Comment: These are clever, but I sure hope the OP doesn't want this for inside a `form` tag. If he does, as I'm sure you know, he could simply use `fieldset` and `legend`.

Comment: Heh, you're right about that. Might as well go for that anyway if this doesn't work.. not semantically correct but it's better than having to resort to javascript for something like this imo.

Comment: The best solution I found that works well when the screen is resided and without setting the background color of the text is http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDf/268/

Answer (score 40):

#### edit (09/2020)

`display:flex` method seems to be today the most solid and easiest to set in action.

---

**Wrote  Mar 17 '15 at 17:06:**

for later(nowdays ) browser , `display:flex` and `pseudo-elements`  makes it easy to draw without extra markup.

`border-style`, `box-shadow` and even `background` helps too for the makeup if you need it fancy or ugly.
[image: demo below]

```css
h1 {margin-top:50px;
  display:flex;
  background:linear-gradient(to left,gray,lightgray,white,yellow,turquoise);;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  color:white;
  content:'';
  flex:1;
  border-bottom:groove 2px;
  margin:auto 0.25em;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px ;/* ou 0 1px si border-style:ridge */
}
```

```html
<h1>side lines via flex</h1>
```

resources *(added 09/2020)*:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ (see `flex`/`flex-grow` used here)
- https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/ (`margin:auto 0.25em;` used here )

Answer (score 34):

```
   <div class="flex items-center">
      <div class="flex-grow bg bg-gray-300 h-0.5"></div>
      <div class="flex-grow-0 mx-5 text dark:text-white">or</div>
      <div class="flex-grow bg bg-gray-300 h-0.5"></div>
   </div>
```

For all the tailwind lovers out there.
Inspired by WellSpring's answer

[image: Tailwind CSS Create Horizontal Line Divider with labled text words in middle]

Comment: With latest version you can do it without adding extra HTML even more awesome. `before:mr-2 before:block before:flex-1 before:border-b-2 before:border-gray-200 after:ml-2 after:block after:flex-1 after:border-b-2 after:border-gray-200 lg:before:mr-4 lf:after:ml-4`

Answer (score 22):

```css
.hr-sect {
 display: flex;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 align-items: center;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 margin: 8px 0px;
}
.hr-sect::before,
.hr-sect::after {
 content: "";
 flex-grow: 1;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
 height: 1px;
 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 0px;
 margin: 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr-sect">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

```css
div {
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  top: -.7em;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span>text TEXT</span></div>
```

Give the span a padding to make more space between the text and the line.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tUGrf/

Comment: Nice, only problem is that you have to set the background to white and can't set it to transparent.

Comment: in that case you'll have to work with two lines, one on each side. That's going to be difficult to achieve in a clean way..

Comment: My favorite approach so far but unfortunately it doesn't work in email clients for some reason(Gmail mobile & web)

Answer (score 12):

I think the most straightforward way is using CSS grid.

```css
h1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 0.1rem double black;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 8):

I've been looking around for some solutions for this simple decoration and I've found quite a few ones, some weird, some even with JS to calculate the height of the font and bla,bla,bla, then I've read the one on this post and read a comment from **thirtydot** speaking about     `fieldset` and `legend` and I thought that was it.

I'm overriding those 2 elements styles, I guess you could copy the W3C standards for them and include it on your `.middle-line-text` class (or whatever you want to call it) but this is what I did:

```
<fieldset class="featured-header">
    <legend>Your text goes here</legend>
</fieldset>

<style>
.featured-header{
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    text-align: center;
 }

.featured-header legend{
    -webkit-padding-start: 8px; /* It sets the whitespace between the line and the text */
    -webkit-padding-end: 8px; 
    background: transparent; /** It's cool because you don't need to fill your bg-color as you would need to in some of the other examples that you can find (: */
    font-weight: normal; /* I preffer the text to be regular instead of bold  */
    color: YOU_CHOOSE;
}   

</style>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/legnaleama/3t7wjpa2/

I've played with the border styles and it also works in Android ;) (Tested on kitkat 4.XX)

EDIT:

Following Bekerov Artur's idea which is a nice option too, I've changed the .png base64 image to create the stroke with an .SVG so you can render in any resolution and also change the colour of the element without any other software involved :)

```
/* SVG solution based on Bekerov Artur */
/* Flexible solution, scalable, adaptable and also color customizable*/
.stroke {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='1px' height='1px' viewBox='0 0 1 1' enable-background='new 0 0 1 1' fill='%23ff6600' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='1' height='1'/></svg>");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left;
text-align: center;
}
.stroke h3 {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0 10px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 66px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This gives you fixed length for the lines, but works great.
The lines lengths are controlled by adding or taking '\00a0' (unicode space).

[image]

```css
h1:before, h1:after {
  content:'\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0';
  text-decoration: line-through;
  margin: auto 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>side lines</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

## CSS grids to the rescue

Similar to the `flex` answers above, this can also be done using [CSS Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). This gives you more scope to offset the title, and a more simple way of expanding the gap between the lines (using `grid-template-columns`) and the content (using `grid-gap`).

The benefits of this method over flex methods is the ease of being able to offset the lines, and additionally only needing to add in a gap between columns once (not twice, for each the `:before` and `:after` pseudo element). It is also much more syntactically cleaner and obvious IMO.

```css
h1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid currentColor;
}

h1.offset {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 3fr;
}

h1.biggap {
  grid-gap: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a title</h1>

<h1 class="offset">Offset title</h1>

<h1 class="biggap">Gappy title</h1>

<h1>
  <span>Multi-line<br />title</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution for IE8 and newer...**

**Issues worth noting:**

Using `background-color` to mask a border might not be the best solution. If you have a complex (or unknown) background color (or image), masking will ultimately fail. Also, if you resize the text, you'll notice that white background color (or whatever you set) will start covering up the text on the line above (or below).

You also don't want to *"guesstimate"* how wide the the sections are either, because it makes the styles very inflexible and almost impossible to implement on a responsive site where the width of the content is changing.

**Solution:**

(*View [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RA8v/)*)

Instead of "masking" a border with a `background-color`, use your `display` property.

**HTML**

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="item line"></div>
    <div class="item text">This is a test</div>
    <div class="item line"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.group { display: table; width: 100%; }
.item { display: table-cell; }
.text { white-space: nowrap; width: 1%; padding: 0 10px; }
.line { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; position: relative; top: -.5em; }
```

Resize your text by placing your `font-size` property on the `.group` element.

**Limitations:**

- No multi-line text.  Single lines only.
- HTML markup isn't as elegant
- `top` property on `.line` element needs to be half of `line-height`. So, if you have a `line-height` of `1.5em`, then the `top` should be `-.75em`. This is a limitation because it's not automated, and if you are applying these styles on elements with different line-heights, then you might need to reapply your `line-height` style.

For me, these limitations outweigh the "issues" I noted at the beginning of my answer for most implementations.

Answer (score 4):

I use a table layout to fill the sides dynamically and 0-height, absolute-position divs for dynamic vertical positioning:

[image]

- no hard-coded dimensions
- no images
- no pseudo-elements
- respects background
- control bar appearance

https://jsfiddle.net/eq5gz5xL/18/

I found that a little below true center looks best with text; this can be adjusted where the `55%` is (taller height makes the bar lower). The appearance of the line can be changed where the `border-bottom` is.

```css
.title {
  display: table;
  width: 100% background: linear-gradient(to right, white, lightgray);
}

.title-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.bar-container {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 55%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="title-row">
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not to beat a dead horse, but I was searching for a solution, ended up here, and was myself not satisfied with the options, not least for some reason I wasn't able to get the provided solutions here to work well for me. (Likely due to errors on my part...) But I've been playing with flexbox and here's something I did get to work for myself.

Some of the settings are hard-wired, but only for purposes of demonstration. I'd think this solution ought to work in just about any modern browser. Just remove/adjust the fixed settings for the .flex-parent class, adjust colors/text/stuff and (I hope) you'll be as happy as I am with this approach.

HTML:

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-child-edge {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
.flex-child-text {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child-edge"></div>
  <div class="flex-child-text">I found this simpler!</div>
  <div class="flex-child-edge"></div>
</div>
```

I also saved my solution here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Wellspring/wupj1y1a/1/

Comment: Simple and sweet, works perfectly with tailwind css as well with this solution, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

I went for a simpler approach:

```css
.box {
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff7777;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.line {
  border: 5px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
}

.text {
  background: #ff7777;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1 class="text">OK THEN LETS GO</h1>
  <hr class="line" />
</div>
```

*Result*

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my simple solution for [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/), using only pre-defined classes:

```html
<div class="py-3 d-flex align-items-center">
    <hr class="flex-grow-1" />
    <div class="badge bg-secondary">OR</div>
    <hr class="flex-grow-1" />
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Horizontal divider with badge in the middle saying "OR"]

You can reuse it as a React component, for example:

```
export default function Divider({ text }) {
    return <div className="py-3 d-flex align-items-center">
        <hr className="flex-grow-1" />
        <div className="badge bg-secondary">{ text }</div>
        <hr className="flex-grow-1" />
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is wondering how to set the heading such that it appears with a fixed distance to the left side (and not centered as presented above), I figured that out by modifying @Puigcerber's code.

```
h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1:before, 
h1:after {
  background-color: #000;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1:before {
  right: 0.3em;
  width: 50px;
}

h1:after {
  left: 0.3em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4r73n/u2jcrqha/).

Answer (score 2):

```
h6 {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}

    h6.background {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-top: 0%;
        width:85%;
        margin-left:6%;
    }

        h6.background span {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0 15px;
        }

        h6.background:before {
            border-top: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
            content: "";
            margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
            position: absolute; /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 95%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

this will help you

between line

Answer (score 2):

**Horizontal** and **Vertical** line with words in the middle

```css
.box{
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/N39wV.jpg");
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
}

/*begin first box*/
.first{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
}

.first span {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    align-items: center;
}
.first .foo{
    top: -8px;
}
.first .bar{
    bottom: -8.5px;
}
.first span:before{
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.first span:after {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.first span:before , .first span:after {
    content: ' ';
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}


/*begin second box*/
.second{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
}

.second span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.second .foo{
    left: -15px;
}
.second .bar{
    right: -15.5px;
}
.second span:before{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.second span:after {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.second span:before , .second span:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 2px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="first">
        <span class="foo">FOO</span>
        <span class="bar">BAR</span>
    </div>

   <br>

    <div class="second">
        <span class="foo">FOO</span>
        <span class="bar">BAR</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is also answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279326/6569224

Answer (score 2):

This code will work properly:

```css
/* پخش زنده*/
  .div-live {
    text-align: center;
}
.span-live {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #b5b5b5;
  
}
.span-live:before,
.span-live:after {
    border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    content: " ";
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 3rem;


}
.span-live:after {
   right: 0;
   left: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="div-live">
            <span class="span-live">پخش زنده</span>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using React with Styled Components. I found that is more easy to just separate elements. Is not the "amazing solution" but it works.

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const Container = styled.div`
  padding-top: 210px;
  padding-left: 50px;  
  display: inline-flex;
`

const Title1 = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  left:40px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -17px;
  padding-left: 40px;
`

const Title2 = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  left:1090px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -17px;
  padding-left: 40px;
`

const Line1 = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  border: solid darkgray 1px;
  margin-right: 90px;
`
const Line2 = styled.div`
  width: 810px;
  border: solid darkgray 1px;
  margin-right: 126px;
`
const Line3 = styled.div`
  width: 178px;
  border: solid darkgray 1px;
`


const Titulos = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Line1/>
            <Title1>
                FEATURED
            </Title1>
            <Line2/>
            <Line1/>
            <Title2>
                EXCLUSIVE
            </Title2>
            <Line3/>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Titulos;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One element dynamic solution with transparency:

```css
h2 {
  display:table; /* fit content width*/
  margin:20px auto; /* center*/
  padding:0 10px; /* control the space between the text and the line */
  box-shadow:0 0 0 100px red; /* control the line length and color here */
  --s:2px; /* control the line thickness*/
  clip-path:
    polygon(0 0,100% 0,
        99%     calc(50% - var(--s)/2),
        200vmax calc(50% - var(--s)/2), 
        200vmax calc(50% + var(--s)/2),
        99%     calc(50% + var(--s)/2),
      100% 100%,0 100%,
        1px     calc(50% + var(--s)/2),
       -200vmax calc(50% + var(--s)/2),
       -200vmax calc(50% - var(--s)/2),
        1px     calc(50% - var(--s)/2));
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<h2>a Title here </h2>
<h2 style="box-shadow:0 0 0 100vmax blue;">Title</h2>
<h2 style="box-shadow:0 0 0 200px green;--s:5px">Another title Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Using Bootstrap 4 pre-defined classes

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col dropdown-divider"></div>
  <div class="col-auto">OR</div>
  <div class="col dropdown-divider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone wants to, IMHO the best solution using CSS is by a flexbox.

Here is an example:

```css
.kw-dvp-HorizonalButton {
    color: #0078d7;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    align-items:center;
}
.kw-dvp-HorizonalButton:before, .kw-dvp-HorizonalButton:after {
    background-color: #0078d7;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:1px;
}
.kw-dvp-HorizonalButton:before {
    order:1;
    flex-grow:1;
    margin-right:8px;
}
.kw-dvp-HorizonalButton:after {
    order: 3;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.kw-dvp-HorizonalButton * {
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
    <div class="kw-dvp-HorizonalButton">
        <span>hello</span>
    </div>
```

This should always result in a perfectly centered aligned content with a line to the left and right, with an easy to control margin between the line and your content.

It creates a line element before and after your top control and set them to order 1,3 in your flex container while setting your content as order 2 (go in the middle).
giving the before/after a grow of 1 will make them consume the most vacant space equally while keeping your content centered.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No pseudo-element, no additional element. Only single div:

I used some CSS variables to control easily.

```css
div {
  --border-height: 2px;
  --border-color: #000;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--border-color),var(--border-color)) 0% 50%/ calc(50% - (var(--space) / 2)) var(--border-height),
              linear-gradient(var(--border-color),var(--border-color)) 100% 50%/ calc(50% - (var(--space) / 2)) var(--border-height);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div style="--space: 100px">Title</div>
<div style="--space: 50px;--border-color: red;--border-height:1px;">Title</div>
<div style="--space: 150px;--border-color: green;">Longer Text</div>
```

But the above method is not dynamic. You have to change the `--space` variable according to the text length.

Answer (score 1):

This might go a bit beyond the question, but I believe this does help others with similar problems.

If you require multiple cells and do not want to specify a background color explicitly you have to use markup for every part of the line.

This allows you to use a full flex line to position the elements whereever and is usefull for e.g. expander

```css
.title-hr {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: start;
  display: flex;
}

.title-hr>span {
  padding: 0 0.4em;
}
  
.title-hr>.hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin: 0.34em 0 0.35em;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.title-hr>.hr.fix {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-hr">
  <span>+</span>
  <span class="hr fix"></span>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span class="hr"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using Flexbox

```css
#title-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.title{
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.line{
  flex:1;
  height:1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<section id='title-wrapper'>
  <div class='line'></div>
  <div class='title'>some text</div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but you could try using a horizontal rule and pushing the text above its top margin. You will need a fixed width on your paragraph tag and a background too. It's a little hacky and I don't know if it will work on all browsers, and you need to set the negative margin based on the size of the font. Works on chrome though.

```
<style>   
 p{ margin-top:-20px; background:#fff; width:20px;}
</style>

<hr><p>def</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried most of the ways suggested but ends with some problems like full width, or Not suitable for dynamic content. Finally i modified a code, and works perfectly.  This example code will draw those lines before and after, and it is flexible in content change. Center aligned too.

**HTML**

```
        <div style="text-align:center"> 
            <h1>
                <span >S</span>
            </h1> 
        </div> 

        <div style="text-align:center"> 
            <h1>
                <span >Long text</span>
            </h1> 
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
      h1 {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 span {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0 10px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        h1:before {
            background: #ddd;
            content: "";
            height: 1px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: calc(100% + 50px);//Support in modern browsers
            left: -25px;
        }

        h1:before {
            left: ;
        }
```

Result: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fasilkk/vowqfnb9/

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution works perfectly fine...

HTML

`<h2 class="strikethough"><span>Testing Text</span></h2>`

CSS

```
.strikethough {
 width:100%; 
 text-align:left; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcbc; 
 overflow: inherit;
 margin:0px 0 30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 color:#757575;
 }
.strikethough span {
 background:#fff; 
 padding:0 20px 0px 0px;
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

People who are using Bootstrap 4 can achieve with this method. classes mentioned in HTML code are from Bootstrap 4.

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

h1:before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   border-top: solid 2px blue;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 h1 span {
   background: #fff;
   left: 12%;
   padding: 0 15px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;
 }
```

And write your HTML like this

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
  <h1><span> Title </span> </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that requires only 2 properties and easy to update using CSS variables:

```css
h2 {
  --s: 3px;   /* the thickness */
  --c: red;   /* the color */
  --w: 100px; /* the width */
  --g: 10px;  /* the gap */
  border: 1px solid;
  border-image: 
     linear-gradient(
       #0000      calc(50% - var(--s)/2),
       var(--c) 0 calc(50% + var(--s)/2),
       #0000    0) 
    0 1/0 var(--w)/0 calc(var(--w) + var(--g));
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
body {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h2>I am a Title</h2>
<h2 style="--g:50px;--c:purple">Adding some gap </h2>
<h2 style="--w:100vw;--c:blue;--s:7px">Title</h2>
<h2 style="--c:green;--s:5px;--w:50px;--g:20px">Another Title</h2>
```