# CSS 3 how to build dynamic border with dynamic title

Tags: css

I new in CSS 3 but I so confuse with css when I try to design it follow my template

Example my title css in my template will be:

> T-Shirt--------------------------more----

But when Title is too long

> T-Shirt for Kid ----------------------------------more----

My border will be long too. I want my boder auto fix with my title it mean when title too long my border will be fix with my width.

Example my width is `700px;` title is load from database and my border width is `550px;`

and when title is

> T-Shirt--------------------------more----

when title too long my border will be fix

> T-Shirt  For Kid-----------------more----

Like this

How can I do it?

Comment: would you please create a sample with http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You could show your (relevant) html and CSS, then we'd know how to help to best suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're trying to reimplement a [`<fieldset>`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/fieldset/).

Comment: not yet, i just wanna create a straight line with dash border

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure waht your html structure is like, but try this...

```
<div id="main">
    <span class="title">Tshirt</span>
    <span class="more">more</span>
</div>
```

your css

```
#main {position: relative; border-top: 2px solid #000; width: 700px;}

.title {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; margin-top: -10px;}

.more {position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 0; margin-top: -10px;}
```

Hope this helps.. you can move it around by modifying "top, left, right, and "margin-top".

Comment: in this way text be hidden by border - how can i do it without hidden

Comment: Try adjusting the numbers.  Margin-top: -15px, etc.. play around with the code and you will see what does what.

Comment: hi @Josh 

i try it, thank you very much but if i use it in foreach all title will be the same line.

i have no-idea to deal with it :(

Comment: change <div id=main> to <div class=main> and stick that div inside the foreach

Comment: hi @Josh thank for u quick reply but i did it and it till not work my title appear in the same place i need it loop line by line :(

Comment: Add "height: 30px" to .main {}.. -- considering you changed #main to .main

Comment: sorry for reply late because i got fever some days ago.

Ok now i solve my problem with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle 

thank you too for help me Josh!