# 2 Lines behind Headers CSS

Tags: css

I would like to put 2 lines behind my headers on my website. I have found CSS to put one solid line behind the text, but I'd really like to have two lines behind my text of different widths (one a little bit thicker with space in between them).

Would anyone know how to adjust this code to make it possible to have two lines behind the text?

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: red;
}
h1:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.color {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<h1>Header Title Goes Here</h1>
```

And if it's not as simple as just adjusting this code, is there any CSS method I could use to achieve this effect?

Comment: So basically, you want the line to go behind the text..? Like.. http://jsfiddle.net/g7zSZ/ ?

Comment: Not quite. I do want the line to go behind the text, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jxszY/1/ But I would also like a second line, slightly thicker right under the first line. So there would be two lines going behind the text. I just don't know how to acchieve this effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As opposed to setting a height/background, you can alternatively set a border instead.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxszY/2/)

**Updated for margins..**

I added `2%` I don't know if that enough, but you can just change `margin-left` you will notice a difference in `2%`.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dCZR4/1) - with margins.

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 4px;
    content: '\a0';
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
h1:before {
    margin-left: -52%;
    text-align: right;
}
h1:after {
    margin-left:2%;
    text-align:left;
}
.color {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: The third example is perfect. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to add padding on both sides of the words so that there's a little more space between the letters and the lines? I tried adding padding but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perfect! Such a simple fix... I don't know why it's so hard for me to think of these things! lol. Up voting right away!

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work in all browsers.  it fails on safari 5.1 -- only the :after appears where it should.  the :before appears too far to the left (hidden by the overflow setting)

Comment: Check out this approach, which does work on Safari -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/14731123/442650