# Lines Before and After Text (h2) using CSS (or jQuery?)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to put lines before and after h2 texts, like this:

```
----- About Our Line -------------------
```

I found this post: [CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)

But the thing is I have a lot of h2s, so I can't set different widths for individual h2s.

Maybe there's a solution?

Comment: Do you mean all H2s when lines are added should have the same width?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148992/2-lines-behind-headers-css)

Comment: Why not this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5214204/1388588 (http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/)

Comment: Josh's solution worked for me. I just changed the width to 100% and changed the margin of h2:before. Bryan's suggestion could work too, but I didn't want to add an extra span tag. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

```
    h2:before, h2:after {
     content: '----------';
    }
    <div>
      <h2>About Our Line</h2>
    </div>




.h2:before, h2:after {
    content: '----------';
}
```

Comment: While this seems to work, a few explanatory words would be helpful.