# Line text Line setting up code

Tags: html, css, text, line

I've been having trouble setting up my html and css to mimic this picture, [image] . Any tips on how to set it up so it's Line, Text, Line all on the same vertical line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:before/:after` and `top` positioning

## EDIT

See the latest updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g69E9/).

I added:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    position: relative;
}
.line:after
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 49px;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.line h3
{
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

And around your `h3`'s in your HTML I added `<div class="line"></div>`

For example:

```
<div class="line">
    <h3><span style='color: #ff6c00;'>About</span> Me</h3>
</div>
```

**AGAIN**
Change the `top` of `.line` to the amount you need, along with the `background-color` :)

Comment: Thx for the fast response. I applied what you suggested and I got the line, however, it doesn't show on top of the div's background color.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2iqd0xt&s=8#.Uw-OQfldVcg

I tried setting different z-indexes to no help, it either shows on top of everything including the text or behind the div as shown in the pic