# How to make horizontal lines with words in the middle using CSS?

Tags: css

Anyone have an idea how to make horizontal lines with words in the middle using CSS?

The design looks like this below:

```
---------------- Title ------------------
```

Comment: like in the middle or vertically middle but on the right and left of the text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)

Comment: [This tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/) might also be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly `<strike>` tag could be used.

The `<strike>` tag is not supported in `HTML5`. For `HTML5` use `<del>` tag instead.

If you meant horizontal lines with words in the middle... Try this:

HTML:

```
<h2><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
<p>this is some content other</p>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
   line-height: 0.1em;
   margin: 10px 0 20px; 
} 

h2 span { 
    background:#fff; 
    padding:0 10px; 
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S5y2x/

Credits for above code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214204/3739658

I tested it on Firefox and Chrome