# Drawing lines in <li> tag

Tags: html, css

I do have an li element that looks like this:

```
|    Link    |
```

I want it to become like this with a SOLID line:

```
|----Link----|
```

Here is a link to the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/sh9hY/

I have tried putting a hr tag inside the li element and making the hr inline but that failed. The problem im having is that I need the line to wrap around the text. Im clueless on this one.

Comment: Here is a link to the answer http://jsfiddle.net/sh9hY/

Comment: You can try one of the solutions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle

Comment: @user3748315: Hope my answer will help you the way you want.. Check and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's another alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/sh9hY/9/).

```
<hr/><span>Link</span>


li span {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

hr {  
    border: none;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I picked this solution, made for a really nice result!

Only problem is if I have two rows in the li the line will be on the first and not centered. I can live with that since i guess it is hard to solve using only html and css.

Answer (score 6):

Add this into your css:

I have updated the output:

CSS:

```
.content {
  margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
}

ul.events {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0 0 0px 0;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.events li {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(0,169,212);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,169,212);
  font-size:0.9em;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  padding:0px 0;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

ul.events li:before,ul.events li:after{
    content : "----";
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh9hY/6/)

Comment: He'd like solid line: "_I want it to become like this with a SOLID line:_"

Comment: I think OP want to increase the "-" to the end of "|".

Comment: @user1853128 Nope, it is still dashed. Maybe you should use `letter-spacing: -1px;` like Era did.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh9hY/8/)

```
<div class="content">
<ul class="events">
    <li class="green"><a>Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.events li:before,ul.events li:after{
    content: "--------";
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```