# Why does Twitter Bootstrap destroy my CSS layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to implement some part of a page that needs some custom styled table (I know tables are a big no no for this but that is wat im doing so please try to only look at the question.)

The problem is that when I include Bootstrap the line gets destroyed. The easisest way to explain is by looking at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pag5wL9/) and then remove the bootstrap dependency.

The problem I think is in the following CSS:

```
td span {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
hr {  
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This implementation is borrowing ideas from an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424131/drawing-lines-in-li-tag).

Comment: Add your styles after Bootstrap styles.. That way you can override those styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap applies a number of styles to elements directly- in your layout the (main) conflicting rule is `line 159` of `bootstrap-combined.min.css` for `hr` elements:

```
hr {
    margin:20px 0;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

To rectify, add:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/3pag5wL9/1/)

```
hr{
    margin:10px 0;
}
```

To your CSS. Note you may also want to change styling for `a` and `table` elements.

To see what styling Bootstrap applies to each element, use the DOM inspector in you browsers developer tools to step through into the element in questions and its CSS.