# css technique for a horizontal line with image in the middle

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a horizontal line with image in the middle.
I have referred to [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle) , it works great for text but when i add image instead of text, it doesn't works for me. 
Here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigid/87M5u/)

```
 .footer_bottom { 
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cec5ba; 
    line-height:0.1em; 
    margin:10px 0 20px; 
} 
.footer_bottom img { 
    padding:0 10px; 
} 

<div class="footer_bottom"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Google.png/250px-Google.png" alt="Artisan House"></div>
```

ANy help is really appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't call this an answer but maybe it'll help you in some way: http://jsfiddle.net/wB3c6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `position:absolute;` on the image and play with the margin on the div like this `margin:45px 0 20px;`

Css:

```
.footer_bottom img { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
}
```

Check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/87M5u/1/)**

---

**Updated** *(with white background image & vertical centered)*

Add `background:white;` to the `img`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/87M5u/3/)**

---

**Updated after latest comment** 
Just used the post you mentioned and added the image instead of the text...

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/tUGrf/1318/)**

Comment: according to your demo, the line cuts the image. I want line on both sides and image in middle.

Comment: I understand, but this is a way to do it, when you have a white BG on the image..

Comment: @CTravel: +1. Was about to post the same as your second update. I think that is the max that can be obtained with only CSS.

Comment: My image is transparent and I can not add background:#fff

Comment: Can you link us to your image, and clearly explain the requirements (all of them) in your question?