# Horizontal Dash in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I'm busy with this real simple coming soon template, and now I need to make a horizontal dash. I refer to the picture at the bottom of this post. Is there any way in HTML or in CSS to do this?

[image: Dash Example]

Comment: Please search before you ask.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle

Answer (score 2):

kind of a hacky solution, but you can use dashes (or longer dashes like in my case), reduce the letter spacing on the dashes, or use a font with no space between the characters to put them next to each other.

HTML

```
<p>&#x2015;&#x2015;&#x2015; <span>Coming Soon</span> &#x2015;&#x2015;&#x2015;</p>
```

CSS

```
p { font-family: Arial; letter-spacing: -2px;}
p span { letter-spacing: 2px; margin: 0 5px; }
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5nA2/

Answer (score 2):

The character you want to use is the "em-dash", HTML entity `&mdash;`.   In typesetting it is defined as a dash that is the full width of the widest character in the font (usually the letter M).

If you string several together in a row, as in ———— (4 em-dashes) you can make a dash of whatever length you want (in increments of M widths).

In variable-width fonts (where each character can have a different width bounding-box) there's also the "en-dash", `&ndash;`, which is defined (in typesetting) as ½ the width of the em-dash.  Here's a string of 4 en-dashes: ––––  Of course the en-dash won't join up into a solid line in fixed-width fonts.