# How to get a headline to have a horizontal line behind the text?

Tags: css

I'm constructing a site and a piece of the mockup is below

[image]

Since I'm using a content management system that builds the HTML, all I have to work with a single `h3` tag. I want the line behind to have the width of the `div` containing the `h3` tag. Is this possible?

Here's the closest that I can get: http://jsfiddle.net/rmgtq6h6/

```
h3.line-behind { width: auto; position: relative; text-align: center}
    h3.line-behind:after { content: " "; border-top: 3px solid black; position: absolute; width:100%; top: 50%; left: 0; z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: What div do you mean? Do you just want the line not to cross the text, but be as you showed on your image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)

Comment: create an image with the title and a line layered behind it using GIMP or Photoshop? position that where you would like and change the width, height etc using CSS?

Comment: @nicael Yes, I just want the line to not cross the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly this is what are you looking for

```
    h3.line-behind:after {
     position:absolute;
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:150%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  z-index:-1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(25,25,25,0) 0%,
                                        rgba(25,25,25,1) 35%,
                                        rgba(255,255,255,0) 36%,
                                        rgba(255,255,255,0) 65%,
                                        rgba(25,25,25,1) 66%,
                                        rgba(25,25,25,0) 100%);}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmgtq6h6/4/)

or another example more practical add another pseudo-element ::before

```
h3.line-behind:after { position:absolute;
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  z-index:-1;
  background: #000; }
h3.line-behind:before {position:absolute;
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  right:0;
  transform:translateX(50%);
  z-index:-1;
  background: #000; }
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmgtq6h6/5/)

Comment: happy to help, anyway you can simplify your code for second example like this <code>h3.line-behind:after,h3.line-behind:after{/* common code here*/}</code>

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/rmgtq6h6/1/

```css
div.line-behind {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center
}
span {
  content: " ";
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
h3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="line-behind"><span></span>
  <h3>Begin My Giving Journey</h3>
</div>
```

Or take a look here:

http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm

Comment: One of the constraints is that I can't change the HTML

Comment: Can you have a span within a heading tag? Take  a look at these examples: http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer using grid:

```
h1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #CBD5E1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6cq5whgr/

Answer (score 0):

1. Place you text in some container
2. center this text
3. apply some width to the container
4. give the container some background color

```css
h3.line-behind { width: auto; position: relative; text-align: center}
    h3.line-behind:after { content: " "; border-top: 3px solid black; position: absolute; width:100%; top: 50%; left: 0; z-index: -1; }
#container{
   
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:white;
    width:40%;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="line-behind"><div id="container">Begin My Giving Journey</div></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can build is easily with these guaranties

- No images
- No extra
- HTML Scalable (that is, you could add larger text
  and it automatically sizes to fit)
- Fluid
- No JavaScript

---

### Method 1: A Pseudo-Element

```
h1:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
h1 span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7s79zwz5/

---

### Method 2: Adjacent Sibling Selector

```
h1+p {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v9g3d4ua/

---

### Method 3: Linear Gradient

```
h1 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49%, #000000 50%, #000000 51%, #ffffff 52%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(49%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #000000), color-stop(51%, #000000), color-stop(52%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49%, #000000 50%, #000000 51%, #ffffff 52%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49%, #000000 50%, #000000 51%, #ffffff 52%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49%, #000000 50%, #000000 51%, #ffffff 52%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2m30vsgm/