# Create Horizontal Line with Words in the Middle for Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this fiddle on the following post [CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)

http://jsfiddle.net/6RA8v/

Is there anyway to limit the width? I've tried placing a max-width or just width property to both the .group, .item, and .line; however none of it works. I understand there are limitations to placing a width on a display: table-cell.

I have tried the other workarounds on that forum; however they don't work with bootstrap. I need it to work with bootstrap, and I need the background to be transparent (as it's going over an image). Please see the code below:

CSS:

```
.group { 
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
}
.text { 
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="item line"></div>
    <div class="item text">This is a test</div>
    <div class="item line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the css that is provided and use the width property on the group but you have to realign it to the center using `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.group { 
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 
.item {
    display: table-cell;
}
.text { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    top: -.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle which shows a simple way to do it. Just adjust the `padding` if you want shorter lines, and if you want the line to be less in width you can decrease `width` and set a `left` property which will be `100%` minus the `width` divided by 2. So if you have a width of `80%` set the `left` property to `left: 10%;`. Hope it makes sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/yr9dg30b/1/

```
<div>
    <hr>
    <h1>This is text</h1>
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
}

hr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```