# How can i create horizontal line between heading?

Tags: css, wordpress, line

How can i create horizontal line between heading?
 like this --------HEADING------

---

Is it possible to make line look attractive like zig zag or some other customization. 
I am using **wordpress**
 & I know only **css**

---

screenshot - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMQ2j.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [css technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)