# CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle plus vertical borders

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the entire border "up" so the bottom border lines up with the middle of the text. Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle), but I want to keep the left and right borders (they must be pushed up too). The reason for this is the text relates to the information above it.

https://jsfiddle.net/8c039kzy/

My jsfiddle is close but the left / right borders don't go high enough. So I want something like this:

```
|--------Info above is Important!--------|
```

(But the bottom of the left / right borders don't leak down past the horizontal border)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `:before` pseudo element to draw the horizontal line instead.

```css
h5 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
h5:before, h5:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
h5:before {
  top: 50%;
  background: #000;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
h5:after {
  background: #fff;
  top: calc(50% + 1px);
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1px; right: -1px;
}
span {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h5><span>Refer to Info above</span></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this :

```css
h5 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

h5 span {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

h5:before {
  background: black;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

h5:before {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h5><span>Refer to Info above</span></h5>
```

I created a sides line and I used just right and left borders, is this that you want?

Comment: No I hoping to remove the bottom half of the vertical lines. This is close though thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
h5 span:before, h5 span:after {
  display:inline-block;
  content: "";
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: .5em;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h5><span>Refer to Info above</span></h5>
```

other way to do this :) but with lines of given width