# Add centered text to the middle of a hr

Tags: html, css, divider

I'm trying to do this [divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWwsI.png) with CSS. I've tried solutions like this [CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle). But it isn't so elengants when there are a image at bottom.

This is my CSS after my last tried:

```
h5.trust-us {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1.9px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  bottom: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

h5.trust-us  span:before,
h5.trust-us  span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
h5.trust-us  span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
h5.trust-us  span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

And my HTML code:

```
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h5 class="trust-us"><span>CONFÍAN EN NOSOTROS</span></h5>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
          <img src="img/logo-scheneider.png"
               srcset="img/logo-scheneider@2x.png 2x,
                       img/logo-scheneider@3x.png 3x"
               />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
          <img src="img/logo-scheneider.png"
               srcset="img/logo-scheneider@2x.png 2x,
                       img/logo-scheneider@3x.png 3x"
               />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
          <img src="img/logo-scheneider.png"
               srcset="img/logo-scheneider@2x.png 2x,
                       img/logo-scheneider@3x.png 3x"
               />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
          <img src="img/logo-scheneider.png"
               srcset="img/logo-scheneider@2x.png 2x,
                       img/logo-scheneider@3x.png 3x"
               />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center hidden-sm">
          <img src="img/logo-scheneider.png"
               srcset="img/logo-scheneider@2x.png 2x,
                       img/logo-scheneider@3x.png 3x"
               />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But I can't fit the line to 100% of width. [This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtcAL.png)

How I could get it?

Comment: Can you add more of your HTML and CSS code

Comment: You have it now