# Inline Horizontal Rule

Tags: html, css

How to make `hr` element be inline like I do it in snippet, but without `absolute` positioning and without `hr` crossing text?

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello, World? <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say _inline_ but not crossing the text, where do you actually want the line to appear?  Next to the text?  Underneath it?  I don't understand from your question what the objective is

Comment: a generic duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214127/8620333

Comment: @Martin next to the line end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use display flex on the parent and then give the hr flex grow so it fills the rest of the line:

```css
div { display:flex; }

hr {
  flex-grow:1;
  margin-left:10px; /* gap on left */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello, World?</span> <hr>
</div>
```