# Add line on right and left of text

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 0.5;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="strike"><span>Phrase</span></p>
</div>
```

I added a line on left and right of text but with 2 problems:

1. The line gets outside of the P border;
2. The P does not fill the entire width off the container DIV.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Not sure i understand the problem. Have you tried set span width to 100%; or maybe 25% is what you need? the p fill entire width minus 20px margin..

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105358/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `left:0;` and `right:0` to make sure the lines stay within the borders
2. The margins you have on the `p` is what's stopping it from filling the entire width of the container.

Also the span is not really needed.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 0.5;
  /* margin: 20px; to span full width*/
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

p:before,
p:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background:black;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  width: 20%;
}

p:before {
  left: 0;
}

p:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="strike">Phrase</p>
</div>
```

Comment: nowdays, you can relay on flex & psudos, not absolute position to avoid side effects and extra markup ;)

Comment: well of course i'm not providing the ultimate solution here, but rather fixing the issue the op pointed out, also flex can screw you up, in some cases when there's overflow scrollbars don't show up and you lose data.

Comment: with flex and pseudos, lines appear when there is room. it will shrink down to 0 if the content fills up the whole space ;) . absolute take things off the flow, that's why it can screw up things in unexpected ways ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've left your original CSS in but commented much of it out. FlexBox is a good way to achieve what you want (as opposed to `position: absolute` and `position: relative`:

```css
/*body {
  text-align: center;
}*/

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*line-height: 0.5;*/
  /*margin: 20px;*/
  /*text-align: center;*/
}

span {
  display: flex;
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
  align-items: center;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  content: "";
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*height: 5px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /*top: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
}

span:before {
  /*right: 100%;*/
  margin-right: 20px;
}

span:after {
  /*left: 100%;*/
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="strike"><span>Phrase</span></p>
</div>
```