# Adding a horizontal line in between texts in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to add a horizontal line in HTML between texts like shown in this screenshot. From this code, I get a line but not centered between the texts. How can I achieve this?

What I need is something like: Publication---------------------Method.

My code:

```css
.horizontal{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Publication <hr class="horizontal"/>Method</h4>
</div
```

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle

Answer (score 2):

You can set `flex` rules for the `h4` tag. Aligns the center rule `align-items: center`. This example good aligns your line to the center of the words.

```css
.col-sm-4 h4 {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.horizontal{
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Publication <hr class="horizontal"/>Method</h4>
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the pseudo selector `::after`

```css
.horizontal::after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>
        <span class="horizontal">Publication</span> 
        Method
    </h4>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property `text-top`.

```
vertical-align:text-top;
```

```css
.horizontal{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Publication<hr class="horizontal"/>Method</h4>
</div
```