# CSS Line around vertically oriented text

Tags: css, vertical-text

I want to implement a text with a line around it: ------------ TEXT ------------

As it is explained here:
[CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle)

But i need it to be vertically oriented as it would be by setting

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: mixed;
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this instead,**

```css
span:after,span:before{
  content:"\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
h2{
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>vertically</span></h2>
```