# Styling a react component in styled-component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, styling

I am trying to align the component in the center. But I am unable to do so.

**Component snippet:**

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
              <Box marginTop={2} marginBottom={2} display="flex">
                <Box width="100%">
                  <Divider />
                </Box>
                <Box width="100%">
                  <OrLabel>OR</OrLabel>
                </Box>
                <Box width="50%">
                  <Divider />
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Grid>
```

**component styling:**

```
export const OrLabel = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
`;
```

[image]

I tried the `position: center` in the styled-component, but it also giving the same result. How could I move the "OR" to the center?

Comment: The width of your third box is `50%` while the other 2 are `100%`. When calculating the width in relation to the total width, this 50% probably causes an offset.

Comment: You don't have to use absolute positioning, have a look at this and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle

Answer (score 1):

please try it:

```
 <Box style{{display:"flex",alignItem:"center",justyfyContent:"center"}} width="100%"> <OrLabel>OR</OrLabel> </Box>
```