# Paragraph break line hides half the emoji I want in the middle

Tags: html, css, emoji

I want to have a paragraph break with an emoji in the middle, but it keeps showing only the bottom half of the emoji. The top half gets hidden behind the hr-tag line ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ygid.png)).

This is my CSS:

```
hr {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5em 0em 5em 0em;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: medium double #E3E3E1;
  color: #675757;
  text-align: center;
}

hr:after {
  content: "˗ˏˋ☕ˎˊ˗";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: -0.7em;
}
```

I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9u36.png) (made with ms paint lol)

On the after-section I tried these:

- changing display to "block"
- adding a background colour to the after-section, but that still showed only the bottom half of it.
- adding background-color: transparent
- adding "border: 0;"
- adding "z-index: 1;"

On the hr-section I tried these:

- removing the color

All of these solutions led to the same result as in the screenshot above: the top half is hidden behind the line. Why?

It could be that I didn't use the right combination of the above solutions. I don't understand CSS enough to know.

**Edit:** noticed that my question got closed because there's been [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle). The answers to that one all point to a H2-solution though, where I'd put the emoji in the HTML/text. Is there no way to put the emoji in the CSS?
The reason is: I want it to be accesible for screenreaders, which would understand the HR-tag, but would try to read out the HTML everytime, which gets annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is basically with the positioning of the emoji and the `hr` tag overlapping. One way to resolve this(as I would do) is to use `:before` instead of `:after` to apply `top`, `left` and `transform` properties. Something like:

```css
hr {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5em 0em 5em 0em;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: medium double #E3E3E1;
  color: #675757;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

hr:before {
  content: "˗ˏˋ☕ˎˊ˗";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: white; /* Set the background color of the content (emoji) to white, covering the hr border behind it */
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is a paragraph of text. There will be a custom styled horizontal rule below this paragraph with an emoji in the middle.
</p>
<hr>
<p>
  Here's another paragraph of text. The custom horizontal rule above should have an emoji in the middle without being cut off.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pagebreak{
 margin: 20px 0;
 position: relative;
}
.line{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: gray;
}
.emoji{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagebreak">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="emoji">emoji</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, you can leverage the snippets functionality provided in the editor. there is no need to attach the image. If you want I can edit your answer and add that.

Comment: Okay, no problem.

Comment: You can add the answer description if you wish to point out some key information.