# Create borders relative to text?

Tags: html, css

Here's an image showing what I'm trying to pull off.

[image]

So, a line to the left and right of any given text (typically would be some sort of of heading tag), that extends a certain distance on each side of the text (in this case, 65px).

I need something that is fluid in relation to the text itself...the overall width can't be fixed.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line

Comment: @SamHuckaby As far as I can tell, all of those are based on fixed-width. I need a solution that is fluid based on the text itself.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery or other external libraries?

Comment: I am, but I'd prefer this be a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is the one that's worked best for me in the past, you can se the [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rglepper/sq9DS/1/). The code uses ::before and ::after pseudo classes to create the lines and then applies display:table to the text so the box adapts to it's content (I've used h2 for the example) This type of design is normally centered so I've added the margin: 1em auto;
Doing it this way, you don't need to add any extra html. Hope it helps.

```
h2{
    display:table; 
    margin: 1em auto;
}
h2:before, h2:after{
    content:"";
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 65px;
    margin-top:.5em;
}
h2:before{
    float: left;
    margin-right:3px;
}
h2:after{
    float:right;
    margin-left:3px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways.
One way would be setting border around the text, after keeping text inside header tags or div with font settings.
Refer the suggestions in the following link:

[Add centered text to the middle of a <hr/>-like line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line)

Comment: As far as I can tell, all of those are based on fixed-width. I need a solution that is fluid based on the text itself.

Comment: another way..create div with width 100%. inside that create 3 divs and set the middle one width to Auto and set the left and right divs width accordingly(whethre fixed or variable width)..you will achieve what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your html code

```
<fieldset class="title">
    <legend>Some text</legend>
</fieldset>
```

your css code

```
fieldset.title {
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

}
    fieldset {
       width: 50%;                
    }
fieldset.title legend {
    padding: 5px 10px;

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnEyF/)

Comment: The example content does not appear to be form elements. Therefore this would be non-semantic markup.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, it can't be fixed-width. Also mentioned in the post is that these would most likely be heading tags (ie. `h1`, `h2`, etc). So, this won't work.

Comment: added a css for fieldset. This takes care of non fixed-width

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8GjrJ/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            .striked-text {
                position: relative;
            }            
            .striked-text .text {            
                z-index: 10;
                position: relative;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 0 5px;
            }
            .striked-text .line {                
                left: -65px;
                padding: 0 65px;
                border-top: 1px solid gray;
                top: 0.7em;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <span class="striked-text"><span class="text">FAQ</span><span class="line"></span></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For headings you need to define container's width