# How can one achieve this line behind the text?

Tags: html, css

[image: The effect I'm talking about]

Hey!

I want to create a effect like in the image above. The width of those lines need to be dynamic, so they adjust to the text in the middle. I tried it with a table:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><hr /></td>
                    <td><p>The 20th of</p></td>
                    <td><hr /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

But the lines don't just fill up the space like I expected it. How can I fix this? Is there a better approach than using a table?

Edit: Just noticed the typo in the image. Please just ignore it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line

Comment: This comment has the perfect solution for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14731123/1309907

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to make the line a background image, and then put another HTML element in front of it to contain the text:

```
<div class='linebehind'>
    <span class='text'>The 20th of</span>
</div>

<style>
.linebehind {
    background: url('imageWithLine.gif') repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white; /* or whatever colour the background of the line image is */
    padding: 0 5px;
}
</style>
```

Note: this code probably isn't perfect, but it should be more or less what you're looking for with a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Tried that out too, but I have multiple backgrounds, I can't just set it to a color. Thanks anyway!