# Horizontal line in the middle of text

Tags: html, css

I want to display a horizontal line with words in the middle so that it looks like following:

[image]

I'm trying this and doesn't work:

**HTML:**

```
<h2><span>Test</span></h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
h2{
    font-size: 100px;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;    
}

span{
     background: #fff;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top:-25px;
       display: inline-block;
       z-index: 5;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/2ds9a/

Comment: Please see my question, the code does not work that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Please see the accepted answer to the question that this duplicates. That code does work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can used to **css** `:after`

as like this

**HTML**

```
<h2><span  class="line-center">Test</span></h2>
```

**Css**

```
.line-center{
    margin:0;padding:0 10px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
}
h2{

    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;

}
h2:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-top:solid 1px red;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**[LIve Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ds9a/4/)**

Comment: I prefer this approach, its semantic and cleaner  than the answer found here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line you should post your anser on this page as this question will probably get closed.

Comment: Its also worth mentioning that this wont work in old IE

Comment: IE8 + support :after and now check to all css selector http://caniuse.com/

Comment: hi @RohitAzad please visit this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62827/to-display-text-between-horizontal-line-in-magento/62831#62831

he gave an answer as 

a) <div class="horizontal_line">  <h2>Text</h2> </div>

b)<div class="horizontal_line"> <span> Content</span></div> 

please help to get above code lines in single html line code....

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812830/2134785) (suggested by [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)) the following code should work fine for you:

```
<div style="height: 2px; background-color: black; text-align: center">
  <span style="background-color: white; position: relative; top: -0.5em;">
    Section Title
  </span>
</div>
```

For more info take a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line)

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwbpmuss/

Comment: Worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are differents ways to do that,
this is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/zzLnt/

```
   <h2><span class="line"></span><span class="text">Test<span></h2>
   <style> 
    h2{
        font-size: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .line{
        background: #000;
        border-top: solid 1px black;
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        display: block;
        top: 56px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .text{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        z-index: 20;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 34px;
    }
</style>
```