# to display text between horizontal line in magento

Tags: magento

I want to display "text between horizontal line", so

i am  following this link :

[Horizontal line in the middle of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009654/horizontal-line-in-the-middle-of-text)

but in our theme.css file, we already using ".span" & ".h2" classes.

if i use code in above link, it will apply for all the html codes which using these css classes : "span", "h2".

but i don't want that to be happen.

give me some guidance.

Comment: this is the one i  got answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one more span with specific class. or add one more specific class to existing span or h2.