# Title with hr line

Tags: html, css, title

I need to made simple title but with line crossing it. Just like on the picture:
[image]

**Here is CODE:**

- HTML:

  ```
            <div id="intro">
            <div class="bg_big bg_big_green glow"><div id="opac1"><h1>TITLE WITH LINE</h1><p>111</p></div></div>
                <div class="story">
                <div class="float-left">


                </div>
              </div> <!--.story-->


            </div> <!--#intro-->
  ```

All code in here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Bq4/6/)

Comment: http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm - Many options

Comment: This is non trivial. Easiest would be if you examine the original source you took the screenshot from with your browsers debugging console.

Comment: Some very good answers for this Q.

Comment: This is great working with responsive design : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603610/2282880

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634224/465233

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple.

First, give your container a `text-align:center` and your title a `display:inline-block` and `position:relative`. This will center your title and make it a block. Then, using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, style and position lines at either side. I've found this to the the most beneficial method as it will position itself according to the length of you `h1`.

Here's a cleaned up fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/k4Bq4/8/

```
/* The h1's container */
#opac1 {
  text-align:center;
}
h1 {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
h1::before, h1::after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    position:absolute; top:50%; left:-120px;
    width:100px; /* 100px line on either side */
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}
h1::after {
    left:auto; right:-120px; /* make the "after" position on the right side of the h1 */
}
```

Comment: What should I do if I want line to go 100% pages width but with 10px padding from title ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS :before and :after psuedo classes. Chris Coyier has some excellent CSS tutorials you can find [here](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/)

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: red;
}
h1:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.color {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing an example of using psuedo classes to add a line on either side of your [header](http://jsfiddle.net/XWVxk/8/) to achieve the desired effect. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Could use some cleaning up, but this might get you started](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Bq4/7/).

Basically I just played with the `display` properties.

Edit: I'll leave this here because it's still *an* option, but Paulie up there in the comment has a much better set of options.