# How to have a button between a hr line - which then collapses elegantly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like a button between two hr elements with a bit of spacing wither side of the button and for this to remain the same when collapsing. I am using the Bootstrap framework.

[image: I have the desired effect when at full screen.]

I have got the current effect using the second answer from this question:

[Add centered text to the middle of a <hr/>-like line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line)

Therefore, my code is the same as what the answer provided. The first answer doesn't provide the spacing either side of the button.

Using media queries I am able to maintain the desired effect until I reach the 768px width break. Where this happens:

[image: The right hr element continues to collapse into the button, not providing the spacing I need and the left hr element remains the same width.]

I can't continue to use media queries as I would have to apply them per pixel!

There must be an elegant solution to this? I'm assuming better use of columns and width percentages ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bootstrap this solution should work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqw5cu3y/):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Add</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be noted however that using an `<hr>` here would actually be semantically incorrect [**hr @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use image for these lines by simply adding img tag:

**CSS**

```
img{
width:200px;
border:0;
height:10px;
background:url(http://goo.gl/bPZONP);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div><img src="http://goo.gl/bPZONP">Button<img src="http://goo.gl/bPZONP"></div>
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/qW6z9/