# Can I implement hr in inline css?

Tags: html, css

[image: http://imgur.com/OYDKafe]

I am trying to implement as above using HTML and CSS.  I tried making them all as inline display, but that doesn't work. And I don't want to hyphens. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/f14fqv4r/

Comment: There's a ton of answers to this (see j08691's link), most of which are far more elegant, but nonetheless I tried to come up with my own solution (using `display:inline-block`) because I was curious. Result: http://jsfiddle.net/7p125eej/