# Center text in rounded border

Tags: html, css, line, border, vertical-alignment

I want to create a rounded border, and put some text in the middle of the top border like this:

[image]

I tried altering the solution posted on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-hr-like-line), but I couldn't get the bottom border of the text to match up with the border of the div below (the snippet below is using tailwindcss, but you get the idea):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="pt-3">
  <h2 class="w-full text-center border-t rounded-t-lg border-gray-600" style="line-height: 0.1">
    <span class="bg-white px-3 text-sm font-medium">SOME TEXT</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="px-5 pb-5 pt-4 border-b border-r border-l border-gray-600 rounded-md">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Your span already hides the border, keep it on the container and remove it from title.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="pt-3">
  <h2 class="w-full text-center" style="line-height: 0.1">
    <span class="bg-white px-3 text-sm font-medium">SOME TEXT</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="px-5 pb-5 pt-4 border-b border-t border-r border-l border-gray-600 rounded-md">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, I'll just wait a bit to give you the accepted answer in case anyone else has another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only HTML and CSS then you can do it like:

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h3 {
  width: 35px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  background: white;
  padding:0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Text</h1>
</div>
```