# Tailwind CSS align text in center of border on element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to use Tailwind CSS to align some text within the border of another element, so that the border around my element draws a perimeter around the element, and has a break with the text in the center top of the border.

This is being done within a React component.

I am very new to Tailwind CSS. So new, in fact, that my desired goal comes from the [following StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069958/center-text-in-rounded-border), but the solutions provided there do not appear to work.

I have tried the following:

- Adding `mt-5` or `pd-5` to both the class for the `h2` and `span` elements for my label, in an effort to add a margin to move the label down into the border, but this does not seem to work.
- Wrapping the `h2` element containing the `span` element in a `div` and applying `mt-5` or `pd-5` to that, but that also did not work.
- I've also tried editing the margin in-browser via the Chrome Development tools, but that did not help.

My Code:

```js
export default function Skills() {
    return (
        <section id="skills">
            <div className="container px-5 py-10 mx-auto">
                <div className="pt-3">
                    <h2 className="w-full text-center leading-border-text mt-5">
                        <span className="text-sm font-medium">My desired label</span>
                    </h2>
                    <div className="flex flex-wrap px-5 pb-5 pt-4 border-b border-t border-r border-l border-gray-600 rounded-md">
                        Some content here.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

The `leading-border-text` TailwindCSS class is one that I have defined in my `tailwind.config.js` to simply add a custom line height of 0.1.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      lineHeight: {
        'border-text': '0.1'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is what my code currently renders:

[image]

And I'd like for that text, `My desired label` to be in-line with the border just below it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would `absolute`ly position the label in a `relative` parent element like so:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div class="bg-gray-700 min-h-screen text-gray-400">

  <!-- Skills() -->
  <div class="container mx-auto px-5 py-10">
    <div class="relative rounded-md border border-gray-600">
      <p class="p-3">Some content here.</p>
      <h2 class="absolute flex top-0 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">
        <span class="bg-gray-700 px-2 text-sm font-medium">My desired label</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Skills() -->

</div>
```

This way the label will always be centered on the top line of the relative parent element even if its size changes.

Answer (score 0):

After some more thought, I came up with a solution to my own question.

For some reason that is not immediately clear to me, adding `mt-5` did not move the label down but adding a negative margin-bottom class, in my case `-mb-2`, did. I would love it if someone could explain why this is the case.

My solution code:

```js
export default function Skills() {
    return (
        <section id="skills">
            <div className="container px-5 py-10 mx-auto">
                <div className="pt-3">
                    <h2 className="w-full text-center leading-border-text -mb-2 pr-2 pl-2">
                        <span className="bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium">My desired label</span>
                    </h2>
                    <div className="flex flex-wrap px-5 pb-5 pt-4 border-b border-t border-r border-l border-gray-600 rounded-md">
                        Some content here.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

What my solution code renders:

[image]

Comment: That is because margins sometimes can overlap each other or other elements that are below or above that particular element.
It's always better to use padding if you can.
When you put a negative margin you can literally move an element in the opposite direction.
Look this way: Above that H2, you did not have space to push element from above because margin overlap div (his parent). Instead you pull H2 down with negative margin