# Horizontal Line in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, jss

I have a login page that has two login buttons. One for regular login and the other for login with google. I'm trying to achieve a style with horizontal line with the "OR" word. Something in the picture attached.

[image]

My problem how can i put the lines on the sides of the "OR" word. I don't think the `RemoveIcon` suits it?

Pls check my codesandbox here  [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-ts6zi?file=/src/index.js)

```
<div className={classes.center}>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              className={classes.mb2}
            >
              Sign in
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.center}>
            <RemoveIcon />
            OR
            <RemoveIcon />{" "}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.center}>
            <Button type="button" variant="contained">
              Sign in with Google
            </Button>
          </div>
```

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-forked-ptgc9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements to customize the appearance of the lines

```
or: {
  position: "relative",
  marginBottom: "10px",
  "&:before, &:after": {
    content: "''",
    display: "inline-block",
    height: "1px",
    width: "40%",
    background: "#00000044",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%"
  },
  "&:before": {
    transform: "translate(-70%, -50%)"
  },
  "&:after": {
    transform: "translate(70%, -50%)"
  }
}

<div className={`${classes.center} ${classes.or}`}>OR</div>
```

[image: Edit Login (forked)]

Comment: Great work as always. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to only add `alignItems: "center"` to the "center" class

Comment: Here is same issue solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634224/13716883